# Fill PDF fields using iTex -:compatibilities of the versions phone's Android OS, Android Studio, Adobe Acrobat

Tags: itext, compatibility

Using **iText**, I try to **fill the fields in pdf**. The pdf is created from MS Word doc file; the fields are added as *Text Field Tool* in Adobe Acrobat 7.
**The problem**:
in the next code the program interrupts execution of *pdfFormFill.setValue()* (or *PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm()* - it depends on itext7-core version) and jumps out the function, and over few lines in this code to *try{}* - see 3 lines under *////* marking.

It seems, the code to be correct:
but the program jumps to the same line `try{` in the end:

```
       try {
            reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
            writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);

//// from next line:   (when itext7-core:7.1.9 is used)
            PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
            String currentText = form.getField("TxtField").getValueAsString();
            if (!currentText.isEmpty()) {
                //form.getField("Text1").setValue(s1);     //This call was splitted to check in debug the
                PdfFormField pdfFormField = form.getField("TxtField"); //field's default content-it's OK
//// or from next line:   (when itext7-core:7.1.15 is used)
                pdfFormField.setValue(s1);
            }
            pdfDocument.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "PDF filled successfully!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error filling PDF: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
//// prog jumps to next line:
           try {
                if (reader != null) {reader.close();}
                if (writer != null) {writer.close();}
```

QUESTION:
Are there some compatibility requirements between the versions of Android Studio, minimum SDK, phone's Android OS, iText version?
If so, **which version of iText** may be used for the next combination?

**Android Studio** Hedgehog | **2023.1.1** Patch 2;
**Min SDK: API 23 Android 6** must be supported;
**Adobe Acrobat 7** formed the text fields

The pdf file is checked: it is placed on the site, the field may be changed, and pdf with changed fields is printable. Name of the field is checked in debug mode.
In Android Studio:
Manifest: There are permissions for read and write to pdf;
build.gradle: implementation was added and sync;
field in pdf with default text works in debug and it's name is known.
I also tried to use
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.2.1'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-form:7.2.1'
but build shows errors, supposedly for the old Android 6 version.

Comment: do you get an exception if you replace your IOException with just Exception? also, the officially supported Android flavor of iText has `android` sprinkled around. like: `com.itextpdf.android:forms-android:8.0.3`. [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.itextpdf.android).